# Media Queries for the Samsung A20-A70?

Tags: android, css, web, responsive-design, samsung-mobile

Working on a responsive web design for my website, however I need the media queries for the Samsung A series since i can't find it. I own a Samsung A70 but the website looks different on the phone, even though I have a responsive web design for it. I realized that I may not have he correct media queries for it. I have even tried looking up websites containing the proper media queries for each specific phone, but, but none of the websites I've een on had any phone data for the A70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try visiting https://viewportsizer.com/devices/ on your phone. The viewport size is displayed at the top of the page. Most likely the width/height ratio on your phone is throwing your design off.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries for A20 portrait *(but I can't say it is the same of A70)*:
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 694px)

*(I'm not absolutely sure about WebKit but you can try 2.2)*

and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.2)